# The counting problem of paths

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a one-dimension $10$-step random walk with step size $1$, namely $S_n=\sum_{n=1}^{10} X_n$ and $X_i = 1$ or $-1$ for all $i\in\{1,2,...,10\}$. Further we require $S_i \geq 0$ for any $i$. And we have $S_{10} = 4$. How many paths satisfy this condition?

Actually it is a counting problem. It troubles me due to the requirement of $S_i \geq 0$. Could anyone give me some hint? Thank you!

Comment: Well, you must have seven $+1's$ and three $-1's$.   We know $X_1=1$ and we know that as soon as we have three $+1's$ there is no further problem.  Therefore, I'd do the count based on the location of the third 
$+1$.

Comment: The paths that don't satisfy that positivity constraints can all be mapped via reflection (of the part of the path from the point and further where the condition is violated) to paths that go to the reflected end point. So, you can obtain the correct answer by subtracting the number of paths that go to the reflected end point.

Comment: @CountIblis Yes I was thinking of reflection principle. But how to figure out the number of violating paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method I (brute force):  Clearly we must have seven $+1's$ and three $-1's$.  Also clearly, $X_1=1$.   If the third $+1$ occurs after the third $-1$ then we violate positivity, so the third $+1$ can only occur at $X_3,X_4,X_5$.  Easy to count each case.

If it occurs at $X_3$ all subsequent paths are good, so this case contributes $\binom 74=35$

if it occurs at $X_4$ then there are $2$ ways to place the first $-1$ and after that all subsequent paths are good, so $2\times \binom 64=30$.

if it occurs at $X_5$ then there are $2$ ways to place the second $+1$ and after that all subsequent paths are good, so $2\times \binom 54=10$.

Thus the final answer is $$35+30+10=\boxed {75}$$

Method II (reflection):   if you ignore positivity there are $\binom {10}7=120$ paths.  The bad ones touch the line $y=-1$.  From the first point of contact with that line we could reflect our path to get a path that ends at $(10,-6)$.  Thus there is a bijection between bad paths in our problem and paths that end at $(10,-6)$.  There are $\binom {10}8=45$ paths that end at $(10,-6)$ so the answer is $$\binom {10}7-\binom {10}8=120-45=\boxed {75}$$

Comment: By the way, do you know any way using Catalan numbers? Please see my comments under P. Quinton. Thank you!

Comment: Not off hand, though obviously the reflection principle applies to both.  One expression for the Catalan Numbers is a difference of binomial symbols, derived along the same lines I used...so maybe one could set up an algebraic relation, but I don't see it instantly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty big spoiler but you could try to go check up the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: It's not going to be a Catalan number in this case because of the requirement $S_{10} = 4$

Comment: Could you give me more detail. I tried Catalan numbers...

Comment: Yeah I am thinking about having a $3 \times 7$ lattice, and it is equivalent to ask how many paths that do not cross the line $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$, but then I have trouble. I know one way of using brutal force, but it cannot be extended to more general cases.

Comment: Well, of course it is not going to be a Catalan number but you can express it in the same idea.

if we denote $a_{n,k}$ denote the amount of path such that $S_n = k$, then you are looking for $a_{10,4}$.

Observe that for $k>0$, you can write $a_{n+1, k}=a_{n,k-1}+a_{n,k+1}$, if $k=0$, then $a_{n+1, 0}=a_{n, 1}$ and so 
$$a_{10,4}=a_{11,3}-a_{10,3} = a_{12,2}-a_{11,1}-a_{11,1}+a_{10,0}=a_{13,1}-a_{12,0}+a_{10,0}=a_{14,0}-a_{12,0}+a_{10,0}$$

Now observe that for any $n$, we can express $a_{n,0}$ as a Catalan number.

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up the development, it should be :
$$a_{10,4}=a_{11,3}-a_{10,2} = a_{12,2}-a_{11,1}-a_{11,1}+a_{10,0}=a_{13,1}-a_{12,0}-2 a_{12,0}+a_{10,0}=a_{14,0}-3 a_{12,0}+a_{10,0}$$
Observe that $a_{2n,0}$ is the $n$'th Catalan number so $a_{10,4}=429-3\times 132 + 42 = 75$ which matches lulu's answer.

An interesting question is how to generalize this. My guess is $a_{n,2k}=\sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^{k-\ell} {k\choose \ell} a_{n+2\ell,0}$
Let's try to prove this one, obtaining the one for $a_{n,2k+1}$ should be easy from that.

Well no space left.

Comment: The guess is bad, sorry about the spam

Answer (score 1):

If there are $n$ step 1 and $m$ step $-1$ to be placed in a row such that number of 1s is always equal or more than the number of $-1$s, the number of ways is $\frac{n-m+1}{n+1}\binom{n+m}{m}$. In this case, $n=7, m= 3$ and hence equals $\frac{5}{8}\binom{10}{3} = 75$.